# Magento 2: custom validation

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, validation

I have 20 checkbox options (added via custom options) available so the customer can customise the product. I would like to make sure the customer has ticked/checked at least 6 of the checkboxes.

I have written some `JS` to count how many  of the options have been checked and highlight the options in red if fewer than six have been selected, but how do I integrate that JS so the Add to Cart button will run my custom JS as well as the usual validation?

Comment: Currently, you can read more here: http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/. I'm trying to code your custom validation. +1 for your question.